# have delay when updating textview every second in android

Tags: android, textview

I just want to update my text view with countdown timer from 15 to 0 and using following code but it does NOT update it every second and it takes about 3,4 seconds delay to update each time.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initGame();

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("time left : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("finished!");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

for instace it prints :
`time left : 29
 time left: 25
 time left: 22` 
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Usually if the time required for the operation that you are doing  in the `onTick()` method, you will skip the next one. If the only job that you are doing in the `onTick()`, is setting the text, probably that's not the case, so probably your UI thread is pretty busy.

Comment: Try to profile it? Android studio -> tab [Android Monitor] -> sub-tab [Monitors] -> On CPU graph top is button "start method tracing" - should work with debug build. From the docs it looks like `onTick` is called in desired interval when previous `onTick` did finish already, so your code should work (you may try it with only the text view alone without anything else, to see if it works, but as it looks the same as official example, it probably works).

Comment: @GVillani82 except that textview i have 16 imageviews. is it make that delay ? does this way render ui again ? if yes is there a way to partially render ui ? i'm pretty new to android programming !

Comment: @Ped7g thanks for responding.its working fine without imageviews but i need to use other views as well in! how can i achieve to this case ?

Comment: Well, obviously this is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), you don't have problem with countdown timer, but with efficient display of image views. Hard to say what you are doing exactly, and why it is slow, usually imageview does cache it's content in target resolution upon first draw, so as long as you don't change anything, it should be as fast as blitting texture by GPU. As a first step try the profiler data to see, if you have problem with single method or you are simply doing something too complex, and you have to find out some clever trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

[FadingTextView](https://github.com/rosenpin/FadingTextView)  A textview that changes its content automatically every few seconds

You don't have to write extra code.